# Regex to replace the last number in a filename

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm creating functionality to increase the last number in a filename with 1.

Samples:

```
filename01.jpg    =>  filename02.jpg
file01name01.jpg  =>  file01name02.jpg
file01na01me.jpg  =>  file01na02me.jpg
```

I'm struggling with the cases where the original file name contains the same number two or more times. I only want to increase the last number in the filename.

I have done some research, but not been able to find a correct regex. Perhaps someone could help me.

Ideally I want my code to look something like this:

```
var filename = "somefilename";

var newFilename = filename.replace(regex,lastNumber + 1);
```

I'm not sure if it could be done this easy. But I need to figure out the regex before I move on.

---

Thanks to pivmvb, here is my final solution:

```
function getIncreasedFileName(fileName){
    var newFileName = fileName.replace(/(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)$/, 
        function(str, m1, m2, m3) {
            var newstr = (+m2 + 1) + "";

            return m1 + new Array(m2.length+1 - newstr.length).join("0") + newstr + m3;
        })

    return newFileName;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to break the two-digit-with-leading-zero number format if the existing filename is `filename99.jpg`?

Comment: filename.match(/(\d+)[^\d]+$/)[1]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"test01.jpg".replace(/(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)$/, function(str, m1, m2, m3) {
    var newstr = (+m2 + 1) + "";
    return m1 + new Array(3 - newstr.length).join("0") + newstr + m3;
    // m1 === "test"
    //
    // m2 === "01"
    //   So:
    //      +m2 + 1 === 2
    //
    //      (+m2 + 1) + "" === "2"
    //         (convert to string, call this `newstr`)
    //
    //      new Array(3 - newstr.length).join("0") === "0"
    //         (this adds an appropriate amount of leading zeroes
    //         so that the total length is 2)
    //
    // m3 === ".jpg"
});
```

Where:

```
\D+   one or more non-digits
\d+   one or more digits
\D+   one or more non-digits
$     end of string (so it only matches the last digits)
```

Then replace the matched string by a function that returns a new string, after doing the following:

1. adding 1 to the number
2. adding leading zeroes

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
var newFilename = filename.replace(/(\d+)(\D*$)/g ,
                      function(match, c1, c2) {
                        var nextNum = (+c1 + 1);
                        return (nextNum < 10 ? "0" + nextNum : nextNum) + c2;
                      });
```

Note that I used `\D*` to match *zero* or more non-digits between the last number and the end of the string, so that will change "filename.01" to "filename.02" and "name01" to "name02". If you only want to match where there are other characters after the number simply change the `*` to a `+` to match *one* or more non-digits at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the last digits, increase them and then do the replace:

```
m = filename.match(/([0-9][0-9])([^0-9]*)$/);
incr = parseInt(m[1]) +1;
newFilename = filename.replace(/([0-9][0-9])([^0-9]*)$/, incr + "$2");
```

This doesn't add the padding 0 in case number is below zero. I'll let that to you.